# Image loosing it's size iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, itext

I am creating a PDF using iTextSharp and trying to add an image in the header of the PDF. The code is like this

```
public override void OnOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
{
    image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/images/HSBC/hsbc.png"));
    image.ScaleAbsoluteHeight(25);
    image.ScaleAbsoluteWidth(134);
    image.SetAbsolutePosition(38, 800);
}
```

Note : The actual image size is height:25px and width:134px. That's what i am giving in the the `image.ScaleAbsoluteHeight(25)` and `image.ScaleAbsoluteWidth(134)` respectively.

But i don't understand why the image becomes large when PDF generated and it's look awful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your code like :

```
var imagepath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/logo.jpg");
            iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagepath);
            image.SetAbsolutePosition(440, 10);
            image.ScaleToFit(120f, 155.25f);
```

This will definitely work for you.

**Cheers !!**